# XAML custom Panel control inside ScrollViewer: Best practices for layout passes?

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

(For this question, I especially welcome any C++/WinRT nuance, but the layout/lifecycle concepts apply to the runtime in general.)

Suppose we have a bare minimum custom control that inherits directly from Panel, and implements the Measure and Arrange overrides. It might be declared like this in a C++/WinRT project:

```
// MIDL
...
runtimeclass CustomPanel : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Panel
{
    CustomPanel();
}
...


// Header
...
struct CustomPanel : CustomPanelT<CustomPanel>
{
    CustomPanel() = default;
    Windows::Foundation::Size MeasureOverride(Windows::Foundation::Size const& availableSize);
    Windows::Foundation::Size ArrangeOverride(Windows::Foundation::Size const& finalSize);
};
...
```

Or `public class CustomPanel: Panel { ... }` in C#, etc.

And let's give our methods minimal definitions:

```
// C++/WinRT
...
#include "CustomPanel.h"
#include "CustomPanel.g.cpp"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
...

Size CustomPanel::MeasureOverride(Size const& availableSize)
{
    for (auto&& child : Children())
    {
        child.Measure(Size(availableSize));
    }
    return Size(availableSize);
}

Size CustomPanel::ArrangeOverride(Size const& finalSize)
{
    for (auto&& child : Children())
    {
        child.Arrange(Rect(Point(0.0f, 0.0f), child.DesiredSize()))
    }
    return Size(finalSize);
}
...
```

While that code doesn't really do anything beyond the default behavior, it works fine provided the CustomPanel isn't sitting inside a ScrollViewer, like so:

```
<!-- XAML -->
<Grid>
    <local:CustomPanel/>  <!-- Fine in this example. -->
</Grid>
```

vs.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <local:CustomPanel/>  <!-- Very bad in this example. -->
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The problem in the code above, of course, is that the ScrollViewer will pass CustomPanel::MeasureOverride a Size object where one or both of the values will be infinity (along whichever axis/axes it's scrolling on). But passing infinity to one of the panel's children or returning it to the caller isn't allowed. So you check for that in your logic in some way. No problem.

My question is, is there a "right" way or a "wrong" way to account for being a child panel of a ScrollViewer during your Measure computations?

Up till now, I've always handled things something like this: On the initial Measure pass, if the panel receives an infinite available size, then pass `Size(0.0f, 0.0f)` to the panel's children. Subsequently (after a SizeChanged event), I can pass something based off of the panel's ActualWidth/ActualHeight, since they will (I think?) always hold valid values beyond the initial layout pass and SizeChanged event. Is that ill-advised for any reason? What should we base the value we send the panel's child controls in lieu of infinity? Does it even matter?

Comment: Have you tried to place your custom panel inside a Grid and then put the Grid into the ScrollViewer?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Yes, and thank you. That would things much easier, however I'm specifically trying to code against the scenario where a user uses it as the direct descendent of a ScrollViewer. I don't want to prevent that usage outright, and I don't want to presume my way is the best way.